# css3 validation errors with :required, :valid, and :invalid

Tags: css, css-selectors, w3c-validation

I keep getting CSS3 validation errors from W3C for my CSS code and am not sure why. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code.

```
input:required, input[required] {
    border: 2px solid red;
    color: #800000;
}
input:valid {
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: #800000;
}
input:invalid {
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 2px solid red;

}
```

Comment: :invalid supports IE>=10.0

Comment: Just a reminder: maybe you could accept an answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 3):

Your CSS is valid. The validator just doesn't recognize the `:required`, `:valid` and `:invalid` pseudo-classes. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo-classes such as [`:required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3arequired) are not part of CSS, even CSS3, according to definitions applied by the W3C CSS Validator. Generally, what the validator sees as CSS3 is CSS specifications published as W3C Recommendation, Proposed Recommendation, or Candidate Recommendation. Less mature specifications (mostly Working Drafts) are usually not included. There is no official statement on this; it just seems to be the adopted approach.

Thus, for the time being, you need to check manually whether your use of such constructs matches the documents that you wish to adhere to.

Note that Working Draft documents may change at any moment without notice and carry a boilerplate text that they should not be cited except as work in progress. Moreover, implementation status varies a lot.

However, these pseudo-classes are special in the sense that on the CSS track, they are still at a Working Draft level, but they are widely implemented in modern browsers and they have a de facto standard definition in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html#pseudo-classes). (It’s odd that an HTML specification defines CSS constructs, but apparently its authors were frustrated at the slow progress on the CSS track.)

Comment: The validator does recognize large parts of modules that are still Working Drafts, for example most of css3-ui (where the pseudo-classes in question originate) and transitions/transforms/animations. The reason HTML5 defines these pseudo-classes is because they are document language dependent by design; CSS does not know how a document language considers an element to be "valid" or "invalid", if at all; so HTML must define it in order for user agents to apply these pseudo-classes to document trees correctly.